# Feed the result of a Map/Reduce Index to another for further reduction

Tags: c#, linq, mapreduce, ravendb

I have a collection for which I need to determine a total running sum of values. The document looks like this (massively simplified and anonimized):

```
public class Entry
{
    public string id {get;set;}
    public string CompanyId {get;set;}
    public string CustomerId {get;set;}
    public decimal PurchaseAmount {get;set;}
    public bool VoidAllEntries {get;set;}
    public DateTime CreatedOn {get;set;}
    // and many others that are irrelevant to this question
}
```

I made a Map/Reduce index to try and break down the values into groups, grouped by `CompanyId` and `CustomerId`. I'm interested in getting the latest `Entry` (based on `CreatedOn`) from each group, to then boil everything down to the total of `PurchaseAmount`. The reason I need it to work this way is because if the latest `Entry`'s `VoidAllEntries` property is true, I need to not count the `PurchaseAmount` in the grand total. So the index result looks like this:

```
public class SummaryResult
{
    public string CompanyId {get;set;}
    public string CustomerId {get;set;}
    public decimal PurchaseAmount {get;set;}
    public bool VoidAllEntries {get;set;}
    public DateTime CreatedOn {get;set;}
}
```

My current Map/Reduce Index methods looks like this:

```
// Let's call it SummaryIndex
Map = list => from val in list
              select new
              {
                  val.CompanyId,
                  val.CustomerId,
                  val.VoidAllEntries,
                  PurchaseAmount = val.VoidAllEntries ? 0 : val.PurchaseAmt + val.OtherCosts,
                  val.CreatedOn
               };

Reduce = results => from r in results
                    orderby r.CreatedOn
                    group r by new { r.CompanyId, r.CustomerId }
                    into g
                    let latest = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).First()
                    select new
                    {
                        g.Key.CompanyId,
                        g.Key.CustomerId,
                        latest.VoidAllEntries,
                        latest.CreatedOn,
                        latest.PurchaseAmount
                    };
```

This actually does part of grouping and getting the latest `Entry` extremely well. Now the issue I'm facing is that I can't seem to figure out how to make RavenDB do a second Map/Reduce operation on the server based on these results. In the end I'd like to be able to then narrow it down to just 3 things:

```
public class FinalResult 
{
    public string CompanyId {get;set;}
    public decimal PurchaseGrandTotal {get;set;}
    public decimal Count {get;set;} 
}
```

Where `PurchaseGrandTotal` and `Count` would be the equivalent of me running this on the client:

```
var results = session.Query<SummaryResult, SummaryIndex>()
    .Where(x => x.CompanyId == "companies/1")
    .ToList();

var grandTotal = results.Sum(x => x.PurchaseAmount);
var count = results.Count;
```

The reason I want to do this on the server is because I could be dealing with a big amount of data, and I don't want to have to load everything on the client just to process these summaries. I can't figure out if I can make a second Map/Reduce index in C# that takes the results of SummaryIndex as input.

Any ideas? Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Edit: I had to reword the question because technically speaking, Ayende's answer below is the correct answer to the question as I worded it originally. However, I posted that at 2am and I guess I didn't properly explain my issue. The reason I can't use a Scripted Index is because the results aren't being stored as a document (which is what I led Ayende to believe). Other than Scripted Indexes, is there any other way? Right now I'm just using streaming to manually count the records on the client and it's working fine, but I want to make sure there's no alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

This is supported with Scripted Index Results. 
See the docs

http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/Csharp/server/bundles/scripted-index-results

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. I know it took me all day to reply, but I saw the answer first thing in the morning and looked into it. However, I had to reword my question because I'm not saving my Map/Reduce index results on the server as a document. Now the question reflects my actual situation. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: You can use SIR to take the map/reduce output and save it as a document, then run another map/reduce on it.